# How to convert timestamp to date & time

Tags: mysql, google-bigquery

I am currently working on bigquery(standard sql), where I have a `timestamp` field which I want to convert to `date and time` in 2 separate columns. I tried doing this `select EXTRACT(DATE FROM timestamp) from table` .

I tried casting `timestamp` to `date` as well, but it is giving me an error. Any suggestions would be really appreciated

```
Input

timestamp             
1539167364779001       
1542242226310005
1544881556726002

Expected output

date         time
10/10/2018   3:59:24 PM 
11/15/2018   6:07:06 AM
12/15/2018   7:15:56 PM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the MySQL side...

```
mysql> SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1539167364779001 * 1e-6);
+----------------------------------------+
| FROM_UNIXTIME(1539167364779001 * 1e-6) |
+----------------------------------------+
| 2018-10-10 03:29:24.779001             |
+----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Notes:

- Having a TS in microseconds is rather unusual; where is it coming from?
- I multiplied by one-millionth instead of dividing by a million because the arithmetic rounds *division* to some number of decimal places.
- Are there timezone issues?
- That value should nicely slip into a column declared `TIMESTAMP(6)` or `DATETIME(6)`.
- To remove the leading zero from the hour and/or strip off the fractional sections, use the function `DATE_FORMAT()`.  (Oh, was there an implied am/pm?)  (Oh, you wanted truncation?)